Alternative to Naam Japa
I used to do Naam Japa in the past but since I have come to know about Advaita this practice is unacceptable to my mind. I can't find it logical. Though I have experienced it's mind purifying benefits yet it doesn't satisfy my logical mind. Is there any way I can do something other than Naam japa for mind purification.
Let's say I take a word kindness and recite it every day with bhava and feelings. Won't it generate the same benefits as doing Naam japa. Will doing Naam japa provide any additional benefits than this self invented exercise of reciting the name of a quality?
I understand that one-pointedness is the main goal of mantra or Naam japa but I want to achieve this without using any name of God. The reason behind it is that I used to do Japa of Jai Hanuman everyday. I became too engrossed in this japa that I felt disconnected from my family. Even after making sexual relation with my wife, I felt bad because I was not following the path(Brahmacharya) of my beloved Hanuman Ji. Kindly guide.

Bro it will be very silly to act like siddhas when you aren't one even people in advait do "om" japa see examples of odia baba there is very less chance of getting good results without naam japa it(naam japa) along with brahmacharya is extremely important in spirituality I have heard it from saints

Firstly, Naama Japa or Ishta Devas or Puja and Advaita aren't contraindicatory whatsoever. Adi Shankaraacharya has written many stotrams, some of them are thus:
:Mahishasura Mardini Stotram
:Gangaa Ashtakam
:Narmadaa Ashtakam
:Shiva Aparaadha Kshamaapana Stotram
:Devi Bhujangam
:Ardha Naarishvara Stotram
:Annapurnaa stuti
etc (there's way more).
I'll recommend you actually read Advaita texts (you can begin with Viveka Chudaamani) instead of watching half baked Youtube videos, which appears to be the case here.
Advaita does NOT reject the existence of neither Ishvara, and neither Devataas. Only Neo-Advaita does so to incorporate atheism, for whatever reason. Advaita Vedanta is not Anti Veda, to do so. Indra, Hanumaan, Raama, Surya etc all exist.

Let's say I take a word kindness and recite it every day with bhava and feelings. Won't it generate the same benefits as doing Naam japa. Will doing Naam japa provide any additional benefits than this self invented exercise of reciting the name of a quality?

Naturally it will do so. Because, Devataas all exist, their names have special powers. Puranas mention this everywhere. There's a whole group of creations called AshtottaraShataNaamaavalis and Sahasranaama Stotrams that are related to the high level of efficacy of names of Devataas.

I understand that one-pointedness is the main goal of mantra or Naam japa

That's another effect of Naama Japa, or you can say that they're a means to get there. But, one pointed-ness can occur from you thinking about the image of a bed too, can't it? Naama Japa is special. The special part is the name. Also, it's used to establish a connection with a Devataa. These are far more prominent features of Naama Japa as compared to them being a step towards Samaadhi. The same applies to Mantras.

Even after making sexual relation with my wife, I felt bad because I was not following the path(Brahmacharya) of my beloved Hanuman Ji.

Then, you simply need to pick other names. Alternatively, you can read about BramhaCharya properly. While married, you're allowed to engage in sexual activities on every even Tithi (every other day), as per YajnaValkya Dharma Shastram. This is included in BramhaCharya.
YajnaValkya Dharam Shastra 3.79:


I used to do Japa of Jai Hanuman everyday. I became too engrossed in this japa that I felt disconnected from my family.

That's the point, it's supposed to happen. You cannot want Bhoga while simultaneously be working towards Moksha. Naturally such clashes will arise if you attempt to do so. You should seek out a Guru to slowly address this clash so that you can do the Dharma-Karma needed while also being detached.

Yep also you can read Bhaja Govinda, Atma Shatkam (Or Shivoham) and Dasa Shlokl. Move on to Tattva and Atma bodha. And then from their go unto Vakya Vritti and other texts.
